# Extract Information from Egyptian National ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I did a script to extract information from the Egyptian national ID, e.g. national id is 14 digit ex(29501023201952). It could divide as described below:

```
2 - 990115 - 01 - 0192 - 1

x - yymmdd - ss - iiig - z
```

- `x (2)` is the birth century (2 represent 1900 to 1999, 3 represent  2000 to 2099 .. etc)
- `yymmdd (200115)` is the date of birth, yy(99) year,mm(01) month, dd(15) day
- `ss(01)`  birth governorate coda (88 for people who born in a foreign country, 01 for who born in Cairo, ...etc )
- `iiig(0192)` the sequence in the computer between births in this birthday and
- `g(2)` represent the gender (2,4,6,8 for females and 1,3,5,7,9)
- `z(1)` number  Ministry of Interior added it to validate if the National ID fake or not (1 to 9)

I am looking for some general feedback on how I can improve the structure and efficiency of my code.

```
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import textwrap

governorates = {'01': 'Cairo',
                '02': 'Alexandria',
                '03': 'Port Said',
                '04': 'Suez',
                '11': 'Damietta',
                '12': 'Dakahlia',
                '13': 'Ash Sharqia',
                '14': 'Kaliobeya',
                '15': 'Kafr El - Sheikh',
                '16': 'Gharbia',
                '17': 'Monoufia',
                '18': 'El Beheira',
                '19': 'Ismailia',
                '21': 'Giza',
                '22': 'Beni Suef',
                '23': 'Fayoum',
                '24': 'El Menia',
                '25': 'Assiut',
                '26': 'Sohag',
                '27': 'Qena',
                '28': 'Aswan',
                '29': 'Luxor',
                '31': 'Red Sea',
                '32': 'New Valley',
                '33': 'Matrouh',
                '34': 'North Sinai',
                '35': 'South Sinai',
                '88': 'Foreign'}

fake_national_id_message = 'This ID Not Valid'

def extract_birth_century(birth_century_code: int) -> int:
    """
     extract birth century from national id it's in index 0
    :param birth_century_code: one digit
    :return: birth century
    """
    assert type(birth_century_code) == int, 'birth century code must be int value'
    current_century = get_century_from_year(int(datetime.now().year))
    birth_century = birth_century_code + 18
    assert (birth_century >= 19) and (birth_century <= current_century), fake_national_id_message
    return birth_century


def get_century_from_year(year):
    return year // 100 + 1


def convert_birthdate(birthdate: str) -> str:
    """
    Convert birthday in national id from  fromat yymmdd to yyyy - mm - dd format
    it's from index 0 to 6 in EG national id
    :param birthdate: str
            format cyymmdd, c represent birth century code
    :return: str
            yyyy-mm-dd
    """
    assert len(str(birthdate)) == 7, "birthdate must be 7 digit"
    birth_century = extract_birth_century(int(birthdate[0]))
    birth_year = birthdate[1:3]
    birth_month = birthdate[3:5]
    birth_day = birthdate[5:]
    birth_full_year = (birth_century * 100) - 100 + int(birth_year)
    birthdate_str = '{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(birth_full_year, birth_month, birth_day)
    birthdate_date = datetime.strptime(birthdate_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
    assert birthdate_date <= datetime.now() and birthdate_date >= datetime.strptime('1900-01-01','%Y-%m-%d'), fake_national_id_message
    return birthdate_str


def get_birth_governorate(birth_governorate_coda: str) -> str:
    """
    :param birth_governorate_coda:
            Index 7 and 8 in EG national id
    :return: str
             Birth governorate

    """
    assert type(birth_governorate_coda) == str, 'Birth governorate coda must be string not integer'
    assert len(birth_governorate_coda) == 2, 'Birth governorate coda must be 2 digit'
    assert birth_governorate_coda in governorates, 'Birth governorate coda not valid'
    return governorates[birth_governorate_coda]


def get_gender(gender_code: int) -> str:
    """
    :param gender_code:
            Index 12 in EG National ID

    :return: str
            Gender
    """
    assert type(gender_code) == int and gender_code > 0 and gender_code <= 9, 'gender code not valid'
    if gender_code % 2 == 0:
        return 'Female'
    else:
        return 'Male'


def extract_info_from_national_id(national_id: int):
    """
    Extract information from national EG national ID
    :param national_id: int
            EG national id must be number of 14 digit
    :return: dict
        birth_century
        date_of_birth
        birth_governorate
        sequence_in_computer
        gender
    """
    assert type(national_id) == int, "National ID must be Numbers not string"
    assert len(str(national_id)) == 14, "National ID must be 14 Number "
    national_id_str = str(national_id)
    info ={}
    info['birth_century'] = extract_birth_century(int(national_id_str[0]))
    info['date_of_birth'] = convert_birthdate(national_id_str[0:7])
    info['birth_governorate'] = get_birth_governorate(national_id_str[7:9])
    info['sequence_in_computer'] = national_id_str[9:13]
    info['gender'] = get_gender(int(national_id_str[12]))
    # last_number = national_id_str[13]
    return info


def print_info(information):
    print('Birth Century :', information['birth_century'])
    print('Date Of Birth :', information['date_of_birth'])
    print('Birth Governorate :', information['birth_governorate'])
    print('Gender :', information['gender'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
                                     description=textwrap.dedent('''\
                                     Extract Information from Egyptian National ID
                                       -----------------------------------------
                                                Birth century
                                                Date Of Birth
                                                Birth Governorate
                                                Gender

                                     '''))
    parser.add_argument('national_id', type=int,
                        help="Add The Egyption National ID 14 Digit")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    info = extract_info_from_national_id(args.national_id)
    print_info(info)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like exactly the sort of thing you would use a class for. Not just any class, but an immutable one!

I'd suggest you create a `class EgyptianNationalId` and initialize it from a string. You could then parse out all the fields at the time of creation, and store them using read-only attributes (such as with a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?collections.namedtuple)).

Something like this:

```
import collections
from datetime import datetime as dt

_ENID = collections.namedtuple('_ENID', 'list of fields')

class EgyptianNationalId(_ENID):
    ''' Model an Egyptian National ID string.

    >>> id = EgyptianNationalId('29501023201952')
    >>> 1999 in id.century
    True
    >>> id.birth_date.year == 1995
    True
    >>> id.birth_date.month
    1
    >>> id.birth_date.day
    2
    >>> id.birth_date.governorate
    'New Valley'
    '''        
    century = {
       '1': range(1800, 1900),
       '2': range(1900, 2000),
       '3': range(2000, 2100),
       '4': range(2100, 2200),
    }

    @classmethod
    def from_str(cls, s):
        fields = cls.parse_str(s)
        return cls(*fields)

    @classmethod
    def parse_str(cls, s):
        scent = s[0]
        syymmdd = s[1:7]
        ... other fields ...

        birth_date = dt.strptime(syymmdd, '%y%m%d')
        # TODO: Validate birth_date, maybe against century?

        fields = (
            cls.century[scent],
            birth_date,
            ... other fields ...
        )
        return fields
```

Comment: Perhaps a `dataclass` then?

Comment: A dataclass could work, if the python version is high enough.

Answer (score 2):

At first: well done, your code quality is already at a high level!
Here are some remarks that you could integrate besides the class approach mentioned before.

#### The `assert` statement works only if python is in debug mode

It's not running when you interpret it with optimization flags, see [officialdocs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement). It is meant as a debug tool that helps tracking down bugs. For your purpose of validation I'd suggest implementing a custom function that raises an exception manually.

#### The `assert` statements are scattered in every function

This makes it unnecessarily harder to understand what the function actually does. I recommend either factoring out the asserts, or, and that's what I'd prefer, do in two steps: First do syntax check of the id, meaning a check if the format is correct. Then do all your processing. And second, after the processing, you do a logical check of the data, meaning if the syntactically correct string contained actually meaningful data.

#### The naming of the functions appears inconsistent

In `extract_info_from_national_id()` it reads:

```
info['birth_century'] = extract_birth_century(int(national_id_str[0]))
info['date_of_birth'] = convert_birthdate(national_id_str[0:7])
info['birth_governorate'] = get_birth_governorate(national_id_str[7:9])
info['sequence_in_computer'] = national_id_str[9:13]
info['gender'] = get_gender(int(national_id_str[12]))
```

So every function is meant to convert a string into something more meaningful, which makes me expect a standardized naming pattern. I'd probably stick to `get_something()`.

#### You can build a string splitter

In `extract_info_from_national_id()` you do the string splitting. That mixes different levels of abstraction. One could go for a simple function `split_enid` that returns a dictionary or a named tuple, which holds the different substrings, but nicely accessible by name. Once done, you can use it like this:

```
enid_strs = splid_enid(notional_id)
info['birth_century'] = get_birth_century(enid_strs.birth_century)
info['date_of_birth'] = convert_birthdate(enid_strs.birthdate)
info['birth_governorate'] = get_birth_governorate(splitted_enid.governorate)
...
```

Keep going, I like your code!